# checking if time is in specific interval in C++?

Tags: c++, c

I need to generate values according to time of the day, is there a neat way to accomplish that ?

from 9-12  value should be between x - y

from 6-9   value should be between a - b

is there any other way than getting timeinfo struct and extracting hour out of it?

Comment: That heavily depends on your operating system and the specific libs, you are using... Also I wonder why it is not neat enough to get timeinfo and extract hour? =)

Comment: @SadSido it does not convey the intent when people try to change it and modify for specific stuff. I don't know how to explain..

Thank you :) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [`boost::posix_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

```
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

ptime now = second_clock::local_time();

// You can compare now with other ptime values
ptime nine_o_clock = day_clock::local_day() + hours(9);
ptime twelve_o_clock = day_clock::local_day() + hours(12);

if ((now >= nine_o_clock) && (now < twelve_o_clock))
{
  // Do what you want.
}
```

Comment: day_clock::local_day() returns date_time
which can not be casted into ptime, that's the error I get when I try this. din't check into further as I had to submit that so used the *strftime* instead

Comment: @Gollumn: Sorry, when I typed this I had no compiler on the machine. However, I'm pretty sure there is a way to convert a `gregorian_date` to a `ptime` using some specific constructor or function. Did you check the page I linked ? The `boost` time library is the most complete one I've ever seen, I would be astonished if such a simple thing wasn't possible.